# How to find the difference of Dlls

Tags: windows, qt, dll, mfc

I am using MFC & Qt hybird programming on Windows. I find that every time I compile my program, the output DLLs change, even though I dont change a single word in my program. I view the DLL files in binary, and they differ a little bit.

So I want to find out the difference between the DLLs from different compiling.
And What makes the difference?

Comment: There may be many reasons: Version numbers, timestamps, metadata relating to associated PDB, etc.

Comment: @RogerRowland thanks for your help. I open the DLL files in DumpBin.exe and find that their timestamps are different, as you mentioned above. So, what I can do to avoid the change, or the recompiling of the DLL when my code have not changed?

Comment: @KubaOber Because we dont want to release the DLLs those have not changed at all. And Make size of the patch as small as possible.

Comment: If the DLL was compiled something changed and you have to ship it. Or you project dependencies are wrong and builds are executed even if not needed.

Comment: @xMRi My problem is, even though I dont change my code, I only recompile it, some DLLs change. And I would like to avoid that.

Comment: If your patching depends on the entirety of the DLL (it shouldn't, BTW), it's a simple matter to overwrite the timestamp with a constant value, or perhaps find a linker option that disables the timestamp generation.

Comment: Why do you recompile the code?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help.

Comment: I had already worked on a place where we intentionally implemented a function that every time an application was compiled the executable contained an hash code that would render it different. The main reason was to protect us against modifications not coming from us, when a costumer wanted the source-code. So if the executable was different from what we had supplied to the costumer, we would not assume any responsibility or liability for defects on it.